# How to change color swatches in Flat UI, a Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I've never used color swatches on a website before, and was looking for advice.

I just purchased http://designmodo.com/flat/.  I want to change the default color pattern to one of the swatches.  It sounds like it's a simple process, but I don't know where to look.

Can someone tell me how to change swatch colors?  Maybe the process is similar as within Twtiter Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a /less folder where you can find a "variables.less". There you can do your configuration. Then you need to compile it.

http://lesscss.org/

Or you use an IDE like Netbeans that can compile LESS files.

Comment: thanks! It was the first time I touched lesscss.  Amazing stuff!

Comment: It seems that on FlatUI 1.2.1 the file you have to edit is variables.less as there is no config.less

Comment: @tomor: How does one change the entire theme color of the UI kit?

Comment: thx i changed the filenam, @ Ali Gajani: look in the files and change the colors under the "// Brand colors" section